# How to call class member function from iterator of map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I am not able to call the show function using iterator of map. Is there any way to do this using iterator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class A 
{ 
    int i;
    public: 
    A(int pi):i(pi)   {  cout<<"A()\n"; }
    void show() const { cout<<i<<endl; }
    ~A()   {  cout<<"~A()\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    map<char, A > mymap;
    A a(9) , b(8) , c(7);
    mymap['a'] =  a;
    mymap['b'] =  b;
    mymap['c'] =  c;
    map<char,A >::iterator it;
    for(it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end() ; it++)
        (*(it->second)).show();
    return 0;
}
```

On using `it->second.show()`, I get the error below:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:63:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:61,
>                    from 3: /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple: In instantiation of 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&,
>   std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>,
>   std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {char&&}; long
>   unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0ul}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int
>   ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const char; _T2 = A]':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:1093:63:   required from 'std::pair<_T1,
>   _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {char&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 =
>   const char; _T2 = A]' /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: 
>   required from 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*,
>   _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple, std::tuple<>}; _Tp =
>   std::_Rb_tree_node >]'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:253:4:   required from
>   'static std::_Require::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type>
>   std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&&
>   ...) [with _Tp = std::pair; _Args = {const
>   std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc
>   = std::allocator > >; std::_Require::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> =
>   void]' /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:399:57:   required
>   from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p,
>   (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...))
>   std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...)
>   [with _Tp = std::pair; _Args = {const
>   std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc
>   = std::allocator > >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p,
>   (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) =
>   ]' /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:423:42:   required
>   from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple, std::tuple<>}; _Key =
>   char; _Val = std::pair; _KeyOfValue =
>   std::_Select1st >; _Compare =
>   std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >;
>   std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type =
>   std::_Rb_tree_node >*]'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:1790:64:   required from
>   'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator
>   std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple, std::tuple<>}; _Key =
>   char; _Val = std::pair; _KeyOfValue =
>   std::_Select1st >; _Compare =
>   std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >;
>   std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator =
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key,
>   _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >]'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:519:8:   required from
>   'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key,
>   _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = char; _Tp = A; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >;
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = A; std::map<_Key,
>   _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = char]' 17:14:   required from here /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:1104:70: error: no matching function for
>   call to 'A::A()'
>            second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
>                                                                         ^ /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:1104:70: note: candidates are: 9:5: note:
>   A::A(int) 9:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided 5:7:
>   note: constexpr A::A(const A&) 5:7: note:   candidate expects 1
>   argument, 0 provided

Comment: Not working boss, here is the error shown by the compiler

Comment: If you'd formatted the error message as code and not as quotation it would at least have been almost readable. Now it's just a mess.

Answer (score 2):

1.`it->second` will return `A` directly, not `A*`, you should change

```
(*(it->second)).show();
```

to

```
(it->second).show();
```

2.[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) needs type `A` to be [DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible).

> Inserts value_type(key, T()) if the key does not exist.

But `A` doesn't have the default constructor, you could

```
mymap.insert({'a', a});
```

or as @Jarod42  suggested:

```
mymap.emplace('a', a);
```

to avoid `A` being default constructed.

Comment: or `mymap.emplace('a', a)`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you need a default constructor in A:

```
A() {}
```

compiler will not create default constructor if you have provided any other c-tor.

second thing is how to call your function:

```
it->second.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this? friend.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class A 
{ 
    int i;
public: 
    A(int pi=0):i(pi)   {  cout<<"A()\n"; }
    void show() const { cout<<i<<endl; }
    ~A()   {  cout<<"~A()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    map<char, A > mymap;
    A a(9) , b(8) , c(7);
    mymap['a'] =  a;
    mymap['b'] =  b;
    mymap['c'] =  c;
    map<char,A >::iterator it;
    for(it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end() ; it++)
        it->second.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your troubles

```
    A(int pi=0):i(pi)   {  cout<<"A("<<pi<<")\n"; }
...
    for(it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end() ; it++)
        (it->second).show();
```

u should override operator = to make it work properly